# office js libary token we directly able to use for graph API implement on outlook add-in?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js

i have on angular outlook pluing and want changes EWS API to Graph API.
office js library already provide token so i think we directly use that token for graph API
or need to install any other library like msal or angular-msal

want to implement graph API on outlook pluing with officejs library if possible
if any reference so please share here so help us community and mine also

Comment: Here are a few docs related to Graph API in the context of Outlook add-ins:
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/#outlook-rest-api-via-microsoft-graph
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph

Please let us know if this answers your question.